# Como adicionar Jquery em uma pagina wordpress?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.data-encerramento').each(function (){
        var $this = $(this);
        var timestamp = $this.html();

        var a = new Date( timestamp * 1000);
        var months = ['Jan','Fev','Mar','Abr','Mai','Jun','Jul','Ago','Set','Out','Nov','Dez'];

        var year = a.getFullYear();
        var month = months[a.getMonth()];
        var date = a.getDate();

        var time = date + ' ' + month + ' ' + year;

        alert($this.html());

        $this.html(time);
    });
});
```

Tenho esse código e da erro de $.
Preciso colocar esse trecho em um post do wordpress.

Não tenho acesso ao ftp, pessoal do ti não libera arquivos.

Não consigo editar o theme.

Como faria esse código em javascript apenas???

Comment: Se for igual na empresa que trabalho, altere `$` para `jQuery`

Answer (score 2):

Encapsule o seu código em uma closure, dessa maneira:

```js
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.data-encerramento').each(function (){
            var $this = $(this);
            var timestamp = $this.html();

            var a = new Date( timestamp * 1000);
            var months = ['Jan','Fev','Mar','Abr','Mai','Jun','Jul','Ago','Set','Out','Nov','Dez'];

            var year = a.getFullYear();
            var month = months[a.getMonth()];
            var date = a.getDate();

            var time = date + ' ' + month + ' ' + year;

            alert($this.html());

            $this.html(time);
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Desse jeito o código não vai ficar exposto no escopo global e tu garante que no escopo da tua função `$` vai ser sempre `jQuery`.

É uma prática comum e é mostrado no [jquery-plugin-boilerplate](https://github.com/jquery-boilerplate/jquery-patterns/blob/master/patterns/jquery.basic.plugin-boilerplate.js).

Comment: Mesmo assim nao funcionou pra mim

Comment: Então tua página não está carregando o jQuery ou tem algum outro script alterando o valor da variável `window.jQuery`.
Ou teu erro não tem nada a ver com `$`

Comment: Tem algum meio de identificar isso ?? eu estou bem limitado com relação a acessos de arquivos e permissões.

Comment: Entra no console do browser e digita: `jQuery.fn.jquery`. Isso vai te retornar a versão do jQuery ou dar erro caso o jQuery não esteja carregado.
Se mostrar a versão certinho quer dizer que meu código acima vai funcionar... Se não funcionou tem que ver onde está o erro, pois pelo o que tu postou parece tudo ok

Answer (score 1):

Tente trocar o `$` por `jQuery` por exemplo `jQuery(document)` como sugeriu o @Marcelo Bonifazio. Em alguns casos, pode ser necessário carregar o script como abaixo, isso pode ser feito usando uma página de template por exemplo:

```
 wp_register_script( 'jquery', ( 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js' ), false, null, true );
 wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
```

Fontes:
https://codex.wordpress.org/pt-br:Function_Reference/wp_register_script
http://wpsnipp.com/index.php/functions-php/loading-jquery-from-the-google-cdn-with-wp_register_script/